# The anti-forgery cookie token and form field token do not match MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

in My case, I am getting the issue

The anti-forgery cookie token and form field token do not match.

I have multiple servers, so I have set the same machine key value for all the servers, still not sure why this issue is still there.

I am also using the output cache, when I disable the output cache then I am getting the different issue i.e. "The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken_L015V1AvU1BP0" is not present".

Is there any idea what should I check next.

Comment: Check your reverse proxy configuration. You may need to configure cookie/IP based session affinity on the load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

with the output cache added on the view is getting cached. So if the page get accessed within the cached duration, the _RequestVerificationToken is not rendered fresh from the server.

To fix the issue there are two options

1. Either you can remove the output cache

or of the caching is needed the 2nd option is

2. Render the forgery token in the separate ajax call from the parent view which returns the partial view includes the token. In this approach, your main view will be cached using output cache but the partial view which includes the token will not be cached. So when we submit the parent view form on the server where we are validating the token will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It might be some problem in set up machine key. How did you generate machine key value ? Please double check machine key. Generate machine key in IIS manager. Please go through below links for reference to generate machine key and add it to web config and have that added to all the front ends.

https://support.winhost.com/kb/a1623/how-to-generate-a-machine-key-in-iis-manager.aspx